# Show directions on Baidu maps, start/end encoded in url

Tags: baidu-map

I can calculate directions (json) on ***api.map.baidu*** with: http://api.map.baidu.com/direction?destination=39.988710,116.432340&origin=39.940488,116.355425&mode=driving&coord_type=wgs84

How to form similar url to display same directions over map on https://map.baidu.com/

[image]

I would like to generate urls in my app which load directions on ***map.baidu.com***, but it is hard to guess url because website and documentation I found is on Chinese.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done. If you use map.baidu.com to lookup directions, the url never changes. Which means the entire state of the app is held on the root url `/`.

Comment: I have noticed that, but this does not guarantee that parameters in url are not used when provided. Although it makes is less likely :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through trial and error, I was able to get it to [work](http://api.map.baidu.com/direction?origin=latlng:39.940488,116.355425|name:origin&destination=latlng:39.988710,116.432340|name:destination&mode=driving&region=none&output=html) with the following pattern:

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/direction?origin=latlng:39.940488,116.355425|name:origin&destination=latlng:39.988710,116.432340|name:destination&mode=driving&region=none&output=html
```

The differences between it and what you had include:

- Prefixing each set of coordinates with `latlng:`
- Appending `|name:(point name)` to each set of coordinates, it will not work without putting something here
- Providing the `output=html` parameter

Comment: Works as expected, +50 well deserved :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the API document from baidu map https://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=uri/api/web#service-page-anchor5

2.2.3 Bus, driving and walking route planning

Service address

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/direction //PC&Webapp service address
```

Examples

```
http://api.map.baidu.com/direction?origin=latlng:34.264642646862,108.95108518068|name:My home&destination=Great Wild Goose Pagoda&mode=driving&region=Xi'an&output=html&src=webapp.baidu.openAPIdemo

//Call up Baidu PC or Web map to show the driving directions of "Xi'an" from (lat: 34.264642646862, lng: 108.95108518068) "My home" to "Dayan Tower".
```